# Struts 2's XML validation Error

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

I'm working on Struts2 + Spring Application and used Struts2 XML validation for validate input fields. Validation is working fine for type - "requiredstring",but when I try to validate type - "email" or "int", it is giving this error. please advise me to overcome this one.
I'm using freemarker-2.3.19.jar.
Thanks

```
ERROR [log.Log4JLoggerFactory$Log4JLogger].error() Template processing error: "Expression validator.expression is undefined on line 88, column 109 in template/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl."
Expression validator.expression is undefined on line 88, column 109 in template/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${validator.expression?js_string} [on line 88, column 107 in template/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl]
 in include "/${parameters.templateDir}/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl" [on line 25, column 1 in template/xhtml/form-close.ftl]
```

---

### Java backtrace for programmers:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression validator.expression is undefined on line 88, column 109 in template/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.StringBuiltins$StringBuiltIn._getAsTemplateModel(StringBuiltins.java:71)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)......................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such field `validator.expression` in the input template. Use `validator.regex` instead. If you are not using custom templates download *clean*, *consistent*, *error-free* version of Struts framework and upgrade your application to the latest version. That would help to overcome to resolved bugs to your application.